# How to install Kubernetes dashboard on external IP address?

Tags: kubernetes

How to install Kubernetes dashboard on external IP address? 
Is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: Hi , You just need to change `type=LoadBalancer` in the k8s-dashboard service file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose services and pods in several ways:

- expose the internal ClusterIP service through Ingress, if you have that set up.
- change the service type to use 'type: LoadBalancer', which will try to create an external load balancer.

If you have external IP addresses on your kubernetes nodes, you can also expose the ports directly on the node hosts; however, I would avoid these unless it's a small, test cluster.

- change the service type to 'type: NodePort', which will utilize a port above 30000 on all cluster machines.
- expose the pod directly using 'type: HostPort' in the pod spec.

Depending on your cluster type (Kops-created, GKE, EKS, AKS and so on), different variants may not be setup. Hosted clusters typically support and recommend LoadBalancers, which they charge for, but may or may not have support for NodePort/HostPort.

Another, more important note is that you **must** ensure you protect the dashboard. Running an unprotected dashboard is a sure way of getting your cluster compromised; this recently happened to [Tesla](https://www.wired.com/story/cryptojacking-tesla-amazon-cloud/). A decent writeup on various way to protect yourself was [written by Jo Beda of Heptio](https://blog.heptio.com/on-securing-the-kubernetes-dashboard-16b09b1b7aca)

Comment: Thanks for your big help.